# What is the PSTricks equivalent for " <rotate> of \tkzLabelAngles " and " <arc> of \tkzMarkAngles " in tkz-euclide?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,4)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={0,135,-45}](3;0){A}(3;140){B}(3;-45){D}
\pnode(0,0){O}
\pscircle(O){3}
\pstRotation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,RotAngle=-70]{B}{A}[C]
\pstInterLC[PointNameA=,PosAngle=-135]{B}{C}{O}{A}{M1}{C}
\pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHash,MarkAngleRadius=.5]{C}{B}{A}{$70^\circ$}
\pstMarkAngle[LabelSep=.7]{A}{D}{C}{$110^\circ$}
\pstLineAB[nodesepB=-2.5]{A}{D}
\pstHomO[PosAngle=-30,HomCoef=2,PointSymbol=none]{A}{D}[x]
\pstMarkAngle[Mark=MarkHash,MarkAngleRadius=.5]{C}{D}{x}{}
\psline(A)(B)(C)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I think making double arcs for angle marks has not been implemented yet. You can mimic it by making two angle marks in which one is without label as follows.
- You can rotate the angle label (about its center of gravity) with `\rput` because `LabelMarkOffset` is not for rotating angle label (about its center of gravity).

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-5)(4,4)
\pstTriangle(3;0){A}(3;140){B}(3;-145){C}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=.5]{C}{B}{A}{\rput{45}(0,0){$70^\circ$}}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=.45]{C}{B}{A}{}%
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=.4]{C}{B}{A}{}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _\rput{45}(0,0){$70^\circ$}_ Why it is **(0,0)** ?

Comment: @TrongVuong: Just for fun!